# Chrome 49 causing scroll when draggable element over scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, draggable

This is a change in Chrome 49 from previous versions. In 49, if I have a draggable element, when I drag it over a vertical scrollbar it causes the horizontal scrollbar to scroll to the right, even when it's not accepted.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dragItem").bind("dragstart", function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text", 'data');
  });
});
```

```css
#dropContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#bigContent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
#dragSourceContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#dragItem {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropContainer">
  <div id="bigContent">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dragSourceContainer">
  <div id="dragItem" draggable="true">
    drag me to the left, over top the vertical scrollbar
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a1qnbkeb/

My question is: how can I stop this behaviour without doing some crazy temporary scroll binding? The reason I ask this is because inside "dropContainer", I *do* allow things also to be dragged, and if they are dragged "within" drop container, I do want this behaviour.

I just don't want it when they're dragging *new* things in from outside.